# Activites not startable because of package?

Tags: java, android

I tried to put a preference activity in sub package. The main packages name is my.app.lication.android.credentials and the *main* package is my.app.lication.android

When I put the preference activity in the sub package and configure the manifest like so:

```
<activity 
  android:name="MyCredentials"
  android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>         
      <action android:name="my.app.lication.android.credentials.MyCredentials" />
      <category android:name="my.app.lication.android.credentials.MyCredentials" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

the start fails and I get a ActivityNotFoundException. If I put the MyCredentials class in the main package and configure the manifest like so:

```
<activity 
  android:name="MyCredentials"
  android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>         
      <action android:name="my.app.lication.android.MyCredentials" />
      <category android:name="my.app.lication.android.MyCredentials" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

it works. Can somebody explain why the SDK behaves this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `android:name=".credentials.MyCredentials"` in your first manifest example.

Comment: Yes, now I'm able to start the activity. I'm such a bullock: second line in the manifest the package attribute sets the start point for the names. (package="my.app.lication.android")

Comment: @schlingel: Yes - all Activity names (and Services etc) are relative to that package entry in the manifest.